# Retrieving emails from Exchange sorted by datetime received

Tags: .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, managed-ews

When reading items from an Exchange mailbox, I'd like to be explicit in that they're picked up in order that they were received (datetime received) - earliest first.

How can I specify (on the ItemView?) the sort value(s), and sort direction?

```
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

var service = new ExchangeService();
var inbox = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
var iv = new ItemView(500);

//how to specify sorting, if possible?

var items = service.FindItems(inbox, iv);
if (items.TotalCount > 0)
{
}
```

Using the Exchange Managed Web Services.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633693%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx) shows how to use the `OrderBy` property of `ItemView` to sort results:

```cs
   iv.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Descending);
```